# Swift ObjectMapper - array mapping

Tags: swift

I have a JSON response like:

```
      {
        total_count: 155,
        size: 75,
        authors: [{ name: "test1"
                    id: 1

                 },
                 {name: "test2"
                    id: 2
                 }]
      }
```

I created my object model and use objectMapper for mapping/parsing this json.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON
import ObjectMapper

class Author: Mappable {
    var id: Int!
    var name: String!

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.id <- map["id"]
        self.name <- map["name"]
    }

    static func fromJSONArray(_ json: JSON) -> [Author] {
        var authorArray: [Author] = []
        if json.count > 0 {
            for item in json["authors"]{
                print(item)
                authorArray.append(Mapper<Author>().map(JSONObject: item)!)
            }
        }
        return authorArray
    }
```

With print(item) I can see the objects but, I can't make append work. It is giving "`Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`" error.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not valid.

You can check your JSON validity using [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com) for exemple.

For more safety in your code, avoid usage of `!`.

Replace

`authorArray.append(Mapper<Author>().map(JSONObject: item)!)`

by

```
if let author = (Mapper<Author>().map(JSONObject: item) {
    authorArray.append(author) 
} else {
    print("Unable to create Object from \(item)")
}
```

Comment: JSON is valid I checked using JSONLint. I edited the code as you suggested. I am getting Unable to create .... error. But I can see the item. Is there something wrong with the mapping code?

Comment: Can you add the print of item ? In string mode ?

Comment: Unable to create Object from ("1", {
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "test1"}

Comment: This is not a Valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid JSON ,
As per your json 
**authors** is **dictionary** but **author dictionary** there is no **key**

As well as  inside array there is dictionary but no brackets  and comma

Your correct JSON is

```
authors: [ 
       {
        name: "",
        id: 0
       }

     ]
```

And then your code looks ok to me

```
   if json.count > 0 {
        for item in json["authors"]{
            print(item)
            authorArray.append(Mapper<Author>().map(JSONObject: item)!)
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Try this out

```
      if json.count > 0 {
            for item in json["authors"]{
                print(item)
                 do {
                   let objectData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: item, options: .prettyPrinted)
                  let string = String(data: objectData, encoding: .utf8)
                authorArray.append(Mapper<Author>().map(JSONObject: string)!)

                  } catch {
                     print(error)
                   }
            }
        }
```